# RVM: getting previous ruby's gems for new ruby version

Tags: rubygems, rvm

I previously had `ruby 1.9.3-p286` installed with [rvm](https://rvm.io/) (set as `--default`). I had a ton of gems installed (globally) for this version.

I installed `ruby 1.9.3-p327` today with rvm (and want to set it as the new `--default`), but I now have to somehow re-download/reinstall all of the ruby gems I had previously in `1.9.3-p286`.

Is there any easy way to install all of the gems for `p327` that I had previously installed for `p286` without manually `gem install`ing each again?

**Edit:**
On the [upgrading page for rvm](https://rvm.io/rubies/upgrading/), it mentions something about copying "gemsets" then running `gem update`, but I'm not sure what syntax to use for my use case.

Comment: [Copying gems](https://rvm.io/gemsets/copying/)  It doesn't require gemsets, as stated.  For your case, it would be  `rvm gemset copy 1.9.3-p286 1.9.3-p327`

Comment: @vgoff that looks like it's the answer to the question (Thanks!). Would you mind posting it below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Copying gems](https://rvm.io/gemsets/copying/) It doesn't require gemsets, as stated. For your case, it would be:

`rvm gemset copy 1.9.3-p286 1.9.3-p327`.

Comment: Then I guess deleting the old ruby and gemset after a successful copy is just `rvm remove 1.9.3-p286 && rvm gemset delete 1.9.3-p286`. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, but it might be good to keep it anyway, you can test against the older versions, possibly catching breaks in your code.  I often have several version of older Ruby releases available to test changes made for things I am working on even with the latest Ruby.